# Choosing 4 numbers from 1-20, find the probability the difference between the largest and smallest is k?

Tags: probability, combinatorics

> What is the probability that the difference between the largest and
>   the smallest numbers is k in a subset of four different numbers chosen
>   from 1 trough 20 ( 3 $\leq$ k $\leq$ 20)?

So I know there are ${20 \choose 4}$ total ways, so that is the denominator. After that I'm not sure how to approach this problem. I can think of some examples, like if k = 10, then you have 11-1, 12-2, 13-3, ... 20-10, which is 10 combinations of largest and smallest numbers. And then analogously, for k=9 you have 11, k=8 you have 12. And then because there are four numbers, in the case where say, k=10 and you have 11-1, there are ${10 \choose 2}$ ways to arrange those last two numbers.

With all that said, I'm still not really sure how to turn this into an equation, or if there is any simpler way of approaching this problem. Thanks for the help!

Comment: Let's say that the largest number is 20. Then the smallest number has to be one of 1 to 17. Next assume that the largest is 19. Then the smallest has to be one of 1 to 16. and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For any $k$ you have first to choose the smallest number $s$ less than or equal to $20-k$ and you have exactly $20-k$ choices and after that you have to choose two other numbers between $s+1,\cdots,x+k-1$ and this can be done by $\dbinom {k-1}{n}$ so in total there is exactly $$(20-k)\dbinom {k-1}{2}$$ tuples $(s,a,b,s+k)$ where $s<a<b<s+k$ which satisfy  the difference between the smallest and the greatest is $k$

Comment: Thank you! That makes sense. :)

Answer (score 1):

HINT: Suppose that $m$ and $n$ are the smallest and largest numbers of your four, respectively; clearly $n\ge m+3$, since the other two numbers must lie between $m$ and $n$. Thus, $n-m$ can be anything from $3$ through $19$.

- For $d=3,\ldots,19$, how many pairs $\langle m,n\rangle$ are there with $n=m+d$? How many ways are there to choose two numbers between $m$ and $m+d$?

Put the answers to those two questions together properly, and you’ll have your result.